# Rest Api with different response for Success and Failure

Tags: java, rest, response

I am using very old 3rd party API in my code, which is returning different Response in case of Success and Failure, for example

for Success

```
 SuccessResObj{
     a{...
        b{...
           c{...}
         }
      }
    }
```

Actual SuccessResObj is having around 10-15 nested objects.

for Failure

```
    FailureResObj{
     status="failure because of ...";
     code="400"; // code will always be 400 in case of failure, irrespective of reason of failure
    }
```

FailureResObj is having just 2 variable.

I know its wrong but 3rd party API is not going to change there response , i have to make workaround in my code, how should i handle it because i need to log both scenario in Database.

## Edit

i tried creating a WrapperBean

```
WrapperBean{
 SuccessResObj;
 FailureResObj;
}
```

WrapperBean= ApiResonse();

then its ClassCastExcaption because response is only 1 type of object and i am trying to map it with WrapperBean which is having 2 objects.

A sample handing code for this kind of response will be appreciated.

it can be simply thought of as a method randomly returning 2 different type of response. how should it be handled.

Comment: This is not necessarily wrong. There can be a different schema type per response status code. It's the client's responsibility to know how read each possible schema type.

Comment: what is response code for failure ?is that same with success ?

Comment: so how should i handle it. what am i missing?

Comment: Success is not having any response code , only in case of failure there will be a response code.

Comment: Create a ResponseBean class and create two subclass SuccessResponseBean and FailureResponseBean

Comment: @ Hemant Patel i tried that , created a WrapperBean with Success and Failure Object in it , but Application is not able to map Api response with WrapperBean because response is having only 1 type of object and WrapperBean is having 2.

Comment: What is HTTP status code in case of failure?

Comment: @Nitin Vavdiya  its 400 , in case of any failure , no matter what its 400 only , the status will tell the exact cause.

Comment: You can have two different parsers, one for HTTP status 200 and one for HTTP status 400.

Comment: @Nitin Vavdiya yes thats exactly what i also have in mind , but how can i implement that , can you give me a sample code.

Comment: What are you using to make rest call? resttemplate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170658/discussion-between-shrikant-sharma-and-nitin-vavdiya).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `RestTemplate`, RestTemplate will throw `HttpClientErrorException` in case of none 200 HTTP status.

Here is sample code:

```
try {
    String successResponse = restTemplate.exchange(uri, httpMethod, httpEntity, String.class);
    // convert String in to Object using object mapper
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
    if (e.getStatusCode().value() == 400) {
        String errorResponse = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
        // convert String in to Object using object mapper
        }
    }
}
```

For more on `ObjectMapper` [view this](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson to convert result to a json string.

Examlpe:

```
static class C {
    String val;

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
static class B {
    private C c;

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
static class A {
    private B b;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

static class SuccessResObj {
    private A a;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

static class FailureResObj{
    private String status;
    private String code;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
    c.setVal("Hello World.");
    b.setC(c);
    a.setB(b);
    SuccessResObj successResObj = new SuccessResObj();
    successResObj.setA(a);
    FailureResObj failureResObj = new FailureResObj();
    failureResObj.setCode("400");
    failureResObj.setStatus("failure because of ...");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(successResObj);
    System.out.println(json);
    json = mapper.writeValueAsString(failureResObj);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Output:

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":{"val":"Hello World."}}}}
{"status":"failure because of ...","code":"400"}
```

Then,log the json string to your database :)